# Warning from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, geolocation, subviews

I am getting the following warning when I am calling other view controllers..

> WindowMultivewAppDelegate might not respond to -switchView to view

This is my code in the Firstviewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender{

WindowMultiViewAppDelegate *delegate = (WindowMultiViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication       sharedApplication] delegate];
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[delegate switchView:self toView:secondView.view];

 }
```

this is my code in the Firstviewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {



}

- (IBAction)swapViews:(id)sender;

@end
```

in the appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


 initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];     
}



[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

in the appdelegate.h

```
@interface WindowMultiViewAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,     CLLocationManagerDelegate , MKMapViewDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;

CLLocationManager *locationManager;



}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

I have placed a UInavgationcontroller into the mainWindow.xib which leads to the rootviewcontroller which i named FirstViewController

The application quites in the secondviewcontroller when a button next is pressed which has that action inside

```
- (IBAction)swapNext:(id)sender
{
WindowMultiViewAppDelegate *delegate = (WindowMultiViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MediaViewController *mediaView = [[MediaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MediaViewController" bundle:nil];
[delegate switchView:self toView:mediaView.view];

}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Can anybody tell me how to connect more subviews into the UINavigationController
I want one of this subviews to be a video player - offline- and the other one to be a map which find the user"s location

I am a beginner.... thank you all when I learn I am going to help others :))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is a good introduction on how to write questions that are easy to answer at http://tinyurl.com/sohints. For a start, tag your question with the target platform and programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you define the `switchView:` method anywhere, so it's no surprise that you get a warning about this.

Comment: - (void)switchView:(UIView *)View1 toView:(UIView *)View2
{
 
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationCurve:0.75];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];
 [window addSubview:View2];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 
 
 
}                                         // switchview is in the windowMultiViewAppDelegate.m  ISN"T THAT RIGHT ??and i think that the problem is that the next view is for playing a video file.. do you have any idea how i should do it??

Comment: Why didn't you add this to your question? You pasted a whole bunch of irrelevant code that makes it hard to read, yet left out the single method your warning refers to... You have probably forgotten to declare the method in the header file, therefore the compiler warning.

Comment: Btw, the animationCurve parameter must be a `UIViewAnimationCurve` (which is an `enum`), not a `float`, use something like `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInEaseOut`.

Comment: I am sorry for the mess i am just new into this forum as well and i was panicking a bit as well but thank you for the advice :))